# Storing Bloomberg Data into R Vector

Tags: r, bloomberg

I am using the Rbbg package in Bloomberg.  Currently, I have the ability to pull historical data and store real time data as a variable.  However, this only updates when the command is rerun.  Does anybody have any suggestions as to how to store live ticker prices into a vector?

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to mention that Whit, John and I released a new package [Rblpapi](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rblpapi.html) to CRAN which you can install directly via

```
  install.packages("Rblpapi")
```

It does not depends on Java, and works on Windows, OS X and Linux.

The package has a function 'getTicks()' which does what you want. Here is a futures example (as it is now Sunday evening):

```
R> getTicks("ES1 Index", startTime=Sys.time()-15, endTime=Sys.time())
                      value size
2015-08-23 19:49:47 1960.25    1
2015-08-23 19:49:54 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:57 1960.25    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    7
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    2
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    2
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    9
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    2
2015-08-23 19:50:00 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:00 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:00 1960.50    3
2015-08-23 19:50:01 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    4
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    1
R>
```

That is just trades. We also added a function `getMultipeTicks()` which gets (by default) also Bid and Ask (and other types can be specified).